# Data source for all the roads in the world?

Tags: database, language-agnostic

For no reason in particular, I'm curious what the expected number of feet you would have to walk to find the nearest road is, starting from a random point on the world, facing a random direction. I can write a program to compute this value, given the right data source.

Is there any data source containing all the roads in the world? For example, Google Maps has roads for many cities around the world. Is there any way to get access to that data? Is there an API for this kind of query?

Comment: What is your algorithm? I am not sure what to do even with a single trapezoid.

Comment: The hard part will be the function that takes a latitude, longitude, and a direction, and returns the number of feet to the nearest road. I'll probably construct the world map graph in memory somehow and run a line intersection test. After that, I can just triple integrate across the three variables.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[OpenStreetMaps](http://www.openstreetmap.org/) has the data you are looking for. You might want to look at the [FAQ](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/FAQ). Here is a link to the [data page](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Planet.osm)

Comment: The coverage outside of USA is dodgy at best.
The center of my city (750,000 people) is covered but only biggest routes are marked through the suburbs. Smaller towns are barely marked with the main roads. Secondary roads between towns are missing more often than not. If you want estimate for the USA, go ahead. For the world - no way.

Answer (score 1):

No.

You may get about all roads for 1st world countries, which will be a lot. But countries Somalia, Congo, Bhutan? Half of their roads don't exist on any map, including official maps of their own governments. Half of these that do aren't digitized, only on paper. Many of those are restricted by military.

You may find services that would provide all the easily purchasable civilian-available road maps of the world. But not all roads have been mapped, not all maps digitized and not all digital maps published or made available. And many are hopelessly outdated too.